# Disabling F10 key from moving focus to menu bar in C# Winforms program

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

When I press F10 in my program, the focus is lost from my main program window, and moves to the menu bar. It turns out this strange behavior is common across many Windows apps.

I think it's ugly because the Alt key does the same thing, and we lose a precious function key. Why is Windows doing this, and how can I solve the case for my C# app?

Comment: FYI, this behavior for the F10 shortcut has been around since at least Windows XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301583

Comment: Be careful about changing "ugly" behavior that your users have come to expect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the KeyDown Event for your form, and handle the Keystroke:

```
private void form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ if(e.KeyData == Keys.F10)
    {
        // Do what you want with the F10 key
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Also make sure that your forms KeyPreview is set to true.

Comment: @Mark, actually Dan (the OP) made the corrections.  Since he doesn't have edit privileges, I just helped his changes stick.

Comment: No prob - I'm just grateful for the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

this might solve it for you

http://geekswithblogs.net/aghausman/archive/2009/04/26/disable-special-keys-in-win-app-c.aspx

Comment: That approach is for a more complicated case where you want to override "system" keyboard shortcuts, e.g. Windows key + D.

Answer (score -1):

i used below trick:

```
SendKeys.Send("Alt");
```

this code relieve the form from F10 key.